# How do I properly resize an array?

Tags: math-mode

At the moment my latex code looks like this but I get two errors saying Missing $ inserted. } . I have tried a lot to fix it but nothing helps. I am not sure if I am using a symbol that is messing with math mode or what's wrong.

```
\item \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{\[\displaystyle
    \begin{array}{lp{2mm}cll} 
    (\A \oplus \B) \oplus \B & & \equiv & \big((\A\wedge\neg\B)\vee(\neg\A\wedge\B)\big)\oplus\B & \text{(Def of $\oplus$)}        \\[2mm]
                             & & \equiv & \Big(\big((\A\wedge\neg\B)\vee(\neg\A\wedge\B)\big)\wedge\neg\B\Big)\vee\Big(\neg\big((\A\wedge\neg\B)\vee(\neg\A\wedge\B)\big)\wedge\B\Big)& \text{(Def of $\oplus$)}        \\[2mm]
                             & & \equiv & \Big(\big((\A\wedge\neg\B)\vee(\neg\A\wedge\B)\big)\wedge\neg\B\Big)\vee\Big(\big((\neg\A\vee\B)\wedge(\A\vee\neg\B)\big)\wedge\B\Big)& \text{(De Morgan Laws Double Negation)}        \\[2mm]
                             & & \equiv & \Big(\neg\B\wedge\big((\A\wedge\neg\B)\vee(\neg\A\wedge\B)\big)\Big)\vee\big((\neg\A\vee\B)\wedge\B\wedge(\A\vee\neg\B)\big)& \text{(Associativity Commutativity)}        \\[2mm]
                             & & \equiv & \Big(\neg\B\wedge\big((\A\wedge\neg\B)\vee(\neg\A\wedge\B)\big)\Big)\vee\Big((\neg\A\vee\B)\wedge\big((\B\wedge\A)\vee(\B\wedge\neg\B)\big)\Big)& \text{(Distributivity)}        \\[2mm]
                             & & \equiv & \Big(\neg\B\wedge\big((\A\wedge\neg\B)\vee(\neg\A\wedge\B)\big)\Big)\vee\Big((\neg\A\vee\B)\wedge\big((\B\wedge\A)\vee\false\big)\Big)& \text{(Negation)}        \\[2mm]
                             & & \equiv & \Big(\neg\B\wedge\big((\A\wedge\neg\B)\vee(\neg\A\wedge\B)\big)\Big)\vee\big((\neg\A\vee\B)\wedge\B\wedge\A\big) & \text{(Neutrality Associativity)}        \\[2mm]
                             & & \equiv & \Big(\neg\B\wedge\big((\A\wedge\neg\B)\vee(\neg\A\wedge\B)\big)\Big)\vee(\B\wedge\A) & \text{(Commutativity,Absorption)}       \\[2mm]
                             & & \equiv & \Big(\big(\neg\B\wedge(\A\wedge\neg\B)\big)\vee\big(\neg\B\wedge(\neg\A\wedge\B)\big)\Big)\vee(\B\wedge\A) & \text{(Distributivity)}        \\[2mm]
                             & & \equiv & \Big(\big(\neg\B\wedge\neg\B\wedge\A\big)\vee\big(\neg\B\wedge\B\wedge\neg\A\big)\Big)\vee(\B\wedge\A) & \text{(Associativity Commutativity)}        \\[2mm]
                             & & \equiv & \Big(\big(\neg\B\wedge\A\big)\vee\big(\false\wedge\neg\A\big)\Big)\vee(\B\wedge\A) & \text{(Idempotency Negation)}        \\[2mm]
                             & & \equiv & \big((\neg\B\wedge\A)\vee\false\big)\vee(\B\wedge\A) & \text{(Neutrality)}        \\[2mm]
                             & & \equiv & (\neg\B\wedge\A)\vee(\B\wedge\A) & \text{(Neutrality)}        \\[2mm]
                             & & \equiv & (\A\wedge\neg\B)\vee(\A\wedge\B) & \text{(Commutativity)}        \\[2mm]
                             & & \equiv & \A\wedge(\neg\B\vee\B) & \text{(Distributivity)}        \\[2mm]
                             & & \equiv & \A\wedge\true & \text{(Negation)}        \\[2mm]
                             & & \equiv & \A & \text{(Neutrality)}        \\[2mm] 
    \end{array}\]
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several issues:

1. Don't use `\[...\]` inside an argument.  Use `$...$`.
2. Passed `[t]` to `array` to make it top aligned.
3. Did not fix the fact that the box is a full `\textwidth`, despite it already being indented.  You will need to reexamine that.

Here is the MWE.  p.s. In the future, post a full working example, so we don't have to guess the meaning of things like `\A`, etc.

```
\documentclass{article}
\def\A{A}
\def\B{B}
\def\false{\ne}
\def\true{=}
\usepackage{graphicx,amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\item \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{$\displaystyle
    \begin{array}[t]{lp{2mm}cll} 
    (\A \oplus \B) \oplus \B & & \equiv & \big((\A\wedge\neg\B)\vee(\neg\A\wedge\B)\big)\oplus\B & \text{(Def of $\oplus$)}        \\[2mm]
                             & & \equiv & \Big(\big((\A\wedge\neg\B)\vee(\neg\A\wedge\B)\big)\wedge\neg\B\Big)\vee\Big(\neg\big((\A\wedge\neg\B)\vee(\neg\A\wedge\B)\big)\wedge\B\Big)& \text{(Def of $\oplus$)}        \\[2mm]
                             & & \equiv & \Big(\big((\A\wedge\neg\B)\vee(\neg\A\wedge\B)\big)\wedge\neg\B\Big)\vee\Big(\big((\neg\A\vee\B)\wedge(\A\vee\neg\B)\big)\wedge\B\Big)& \text{(De Morgan Laws Double Negation)}        \\[2mm]
                             & & \equiv & \Big(\neg\B\wedge\big((\A\wedge\neg\B)\vee(\neg\A\wedge\B)\big)\Big)\vee\big((\neg\A\vee\B)\wedge\B\wedge(\A\vee\neg\B)\big)& \text{(Associativity Commutativity)}        \\[2mm]
                             & & \equiv & \Big(\neg\B\wedge\big((\A\wedge\neg\B)\vee(\neg\A\wedge\B)\big)\Big)\vee\Big((\neg\A\vee\B)\wedge\big((\B\wedge\A)\vee(\B\wedge\neg\B)\big)\Big)& \text{(Distributivity)}        \\[2mm]
                             & & \equiv & \Big(\neg\B\wedge\big((\A\wedge\neg\B)\vee(\neg\A\wedge\B)\big)\Big)\vee\Big((\neg\A\vee\B)\wedge\big((\B\wedge\A)\vee\false\big)\Big)& \text{(Negation)}        \\[2mm]
                             & & \equiv & \Big(\neg\B\wedge\big((\A\wedge\neg\B)\vee(\neg\A\wedge\B)\big)\Big)\vee\big((\neg\A\vee\B)\wedge\B\wedge\A\big) & \text{(Neutrality Associativity)}        \\[2mm]
                             & & \equiv & \Big(\neg\B\wedge\big((\A\wedge\neg\B)\vee(\neg\A\wedge\B)\big)\Big)\vee(\B\wedge\A) & \text{(Commutativity,Absorption)}       \\[2mm]
                             & & \equiv & \Big(\big(\neg\B\wedge(\A\wedge\neg\B)\big)\vee\big(\neg\B\wedge(\neg\A\wedge\B)\big)\Big)\vee(\B\wedge\A) & \text{(Distributivity)}        \\[2mm]
                             & & \equiv & \Big(\big(\neg\B\wedge\neg\B\wedge\A\big)\vee\big(\neg\B\wedge\B\wedge\neg\A\big)\Big)\vee(\B\wedge\A) & \text{(Associativity Commutativity)}        \\[2mm]
                             & & \equiv & \Big(\big(\neg\B\wedge\A\big)\vee\big(\false\wedge\neg\A\big)\Big)\vee(\B\wedge\A) & \text{(Idempotency Negation)}        \\[2mm]
                             & & \equiv & \big((\neg\B\wedge\A)\vee\false\big)\vee(\B\wedge\A) & \text{(Neutrality)}        \\[2mm]
                             & & \equiv & (\neg\B\wedge\A)\vee(\B\wedge\A) & \text{(Neutrality)}        \\[2mm]
                             & & \equiv & (\A\wedge\neg\B)\vee(\A\wedge\B) & \text{(Commutativity)}        \\[2mm]
                             & & \equiv & \A\wedge(\neg\B\vee\B) & \text{(Distributivity)}        \\[2mm]
                             & & \equiv & \A\wedge\true & \text{(Negation)}        \\[2mm]
                             & & \equiv & \A & \text{(Neutrality)}        \\[2mm] 
    \end{array}$
    }
    \end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the advices. I will keep them in mind the next time I post something.

Answer (score 0):

You should think at least twenty times before scaling such a big object, with the risk it becomes unreadable.

1. The dimension to be used is `\linewidth`, because you're in a list
2. `\big(` and `\big)` should be `\bigl(` and `\bigr)` to ensure proper spacing
3. `\Big` is too big; I changed them into `\bigl` and `\bigr`.

The best tool for this is `aligned` (the inline version of `align`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{lipsum} % just for the example

\newcommand{\A}{A}
\newcommand{\B}{B}
\newcommand{\false}{\bot}
\newcommand{\true}{\top}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[2]

\begin{itemize}

\item \lipsum[3]

\item 
  \resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{$\!\begin{aligned}[t]
    (\A \oplus \B) \oplus \B 
    & \equiv \bigl((\A\wedge\neg\B)\vee(\neg\A\wedge\B)\bigr)\oplus\B 
  && \text{(Def of $\oplus$)}  \\[2mm]
    & \equiv \bigl(\bigl((\A\wedge\neg\B)\vee(\neg\A\wedge\B)\bigr)\wedge\neg\B\bigr)\vee
      \bigl(\neg\bigl((\A\wedge\neg\B)\vee(\neg\A\wedge\B)\bigr)\wedge\B\bigr)
  && \text{(Def of $\oplus$)}  \\[2mm]
    & \equiv \bigl(\bigl((\A\wedge\neg\B)\vee(\neg\A\wedge\B)\bigr)\wedge\neg\B\bigr)\vee
      \bigl(\bigl((\neg\A\vee\B)\wedge(\A\vee\neg\B)\bigr)\wedge\B\bigr)
  && \text{(De Morgan Laws Double Negation)}  \\[2mm]
    & \equiv \bigl(\neg\B\wedge\bigl((\A\wedge\neg\B)\vee(\neg\A\wedge\B)\bigr)\bigr)\vee
      \bigl((\neg\A\vee\B)\wedge\B\wedge(\A\vee\neg\B)\bigr)
  && \text{(Associativity Commutativity)}  \\[2mm]
    & \equiv \bigl(\neg\B\wedge\bigl((\A\wedge\neg\B)\vee(\neg\A\wedge\B)\bigr)\bigr)\vee
      \bigl((\neg\A\vee\B)\wedge\bigl((\B\wedge\A)\vee(\B\wedge\neg\B)\bigr)\bigr)
  && \text{(Distributivity)}  \\[2mm]
    & \equiv \bigl(\neg\B\wedge\bigl((\A\wedge\neg\B)\vee(\neg\A\wedge\B)\bigr)\bigr)\vee
      \bigl((\neg\A\vee\B)\wedge\bigl((\B\wedge\A)\vee\false\bigr)\bigr)
  && \text{(Negation)}  \\[2mm]
    & \equiv \bigl(\neg\B\wedge\bigl((\A\wedge\neg\B)\vee(\neg\A\wedge\B)\bigr)\bigr)\vee
      \bigl((\neg\A\vee\B)\wedge\B\wedge\A\bigr)
  && \text{(Neutrality Associativity)}  \\[2mm]
    & \equiv \bigl(\neg\B\wedge\bigl((\A\wedge\neg\B)\vee(\neg\A\wedge\B)\bigr)\bigr)\vee
      (\B\wedge\A)
  && \text{(Commutativity,Absorption)} \\[2mm]
    & \equiv \bigl(\bigl(\neg\B\wedge(\A\wedge\neg\B)\bigr)\vee\bigl(\neg\B\wedge
      (\neg\A\wedge\B)\bigr)\bigr)\vee(\B\wedge\A)
  && \text{(Distributivity)}  \\[2mm]
    & \equiv \bigl(\bigl(\neg\B\wedge\neg\B\wedge\A\bigr)\vee\bigl(\neg\B\wedge\B\wedge
      \neg\A\bigr)\bigr)\vee(\B\wedge\A)
  && \text{(Associativity Commutativity)}  \\[2mm]
    & \equiv \bigl(\bigl(\neg\B\wedge\A\bigr)\vee\bigl(\false\wedge\neg\A\bigr)\bigr)\vee
      (\B\wedge\A)
  && \text{(Idempotency Negation)}  \\[2mm]
    & \equiv \bigl((\neg\B\wedge\A)\vee\false\bigr)\vee(\B\wedge\A)
  && \text{(Neutrality)}  \\[2mm]
    & \equiv (\neg\B\wedge\A)\vee(\B\wedge\A)
  && \text{(Neutrality)}  \\[2mm]
    & \equiv (\A\wedge\neg\B)\vee(\A\wedge\B)
  && \text{(Commutativity)}  \\[2mm]
    & \equiv \A\wedge(\neg\B\vee\B)
  && \text{(Distributivity)}  \\[2mm]
    & \equiv \A\wedge\true
  && \text{(Negation)}  \\[2mm]
    & \equiv \A
  && \text{(Neutrality)}  \\[2mm] 
  \end{aligned}$
}% end of \resizebox

\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Oh, and when you have proved that ⊕ is associative, the proof above is

> (*A* ⊕ *B*) ⊕ *B* = *A* ⊕ (*B* ⊕ *B*) = *A* ⊕ ⊥ = *A*

```
$(A\oplus B)\oplus B=A\oplus(B\oplus B)=A\oplus\false=A$
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I am still pretty new to LaTex and I had some trouble getting it done the way I wanted to. It was hard to make the proof readable because the way I proofed the semantic equivalence is kind of messy. Maybe I will just do it the way you did but I am not sure if it's that easy to show that $\oplus$ is associative. I feel like the proof would be a bit shorter but it would just be as messy because the lines get really long.

Comment: @Rard One could try and split the larger formulas at their main connective

Comment: I have already tried that but I would have to do it for almost every line. The proof gets too long and it also just doesn't look nice in my opinion. In my version I have just removed the whitespace at the beginning so it barely fits but I am still not really satisfied yet.