# How to shrink a large table within the default margins?

Tags: spacing, margins

I have this large table and wish to squash it to fit the default margins, is a solution please?

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{nccmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts, graphicx, verbatim, mathtools,amssymb, amsthm, mathrsfs}
\usepackage{array}
    \usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{floatrow}

\begin{document}

\[
\setlength\arraycolsep{3pt} % default:5pt
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.2}
\begin{array}{@{} c | *{8}{c} @{}}
        & (0,(0,0)) & (0,(0,1)) & (0,(1,0)) & (0,(1,1)) & (1,(0,0)) & (1,(0,1)) & (1,(1,0)) & (1,(1,1))\\
 \hline
 (0,(0,0)) & (0,(0,0)) & (0,(0,1)) & (0,(1,0)) & (0,(1,1)) & (1,(0,0)) & (1,(0,1)) & (1,(1,0)) & (1,(1,1))\\
 (0,(0,1)) & (0,(0,1)) & (0,(0,0)) & (0,(1,1)) & (0,(1,0)) & (1,(0,1)) & (1,(0,0)) & (1,(1,1)) & (1,(1,0))\\
 (0,(1,0)) & (0,(1,0)) & (0,(1,1)) & (0,(0,0)) & (0,(0,1)) & (1,(1,0)) & (1,(1,1)) & (1,(0,0)) & (1,(0,1))\\
 (0,(1,1)) & (0,(1,1)) & (0,(1,0)) & (0,(0,1)) & (0,(0,0)) & (1,(1,1)) & (1,(1,0)) & (1,(0,1)) & (1,(0,0))\\
 (1,(0,0)) & (1,(0,0)) & (1,(1,0)) & (1,(0,1)) & (1,(1,1)) & (0,(0,0)) & (0,(1,0)) & (0,(0,1)) & (0,(1,1))\\
 (1,(0,1)) & (1,(0,1)) & (1,(1,1)) & (1,(0,0)) & (1,(1,0)) & (0,(0,1)) & (0,(1,1)) & (0,(0,0)) & (0,(1,0))\\
 (1,(1,0)) & (1,(1,0)) & (1,(0,0)) & (1,(1,1)) & (1,(0,1)) & (0,(1,0)) & (0,(0,0)) & (0,(1,1)) & (0,(0,1))\\
 (1,(1,1)) & (1,(1,1)) & (1,(0,1)) & (1,(1,0)) & (1,(0,0)) & (0,(1,1)) & (0,(0,1)) & (0,(1,0)) & (0,(0,0))\\
\end{array}
\]

\[ % no need for an 'align*' env.
\setlength\arraycolsep{3pt} % default:5pt
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.2}
\begin{array}{@{} c | *{8}{c} @{}}
    & (0,(0,0)) & (0,(0,1)) & (0,(1,0)) & (0,(1,1)) & (1,(0,0)) & (1,(0,1)) & (1,(1,0)) & (1,(1,1))\\
\hline
\chi_{(0,(0,0))} &1 & \phantom{-}1 & \phantom{-}1 & \phantom{-}1 & \phantom{-}1 & \phantom{-}1 & \phantom{-}1 & \phantom{-}1 \\
\chi_{(0,(0,1))} &1 & \phantom{-}1 & \phantom{-}1 & \phantom{-}1 & -1 & -1 & -1 & -1\\
\chi_{(0,(1,0))} &1 & \phantom{-}1 & -1 & -1 & \phantom{-}1 & \phantom{-}1 & -1 & -1\\
\chi_{(0,(1,1))} &1 & \phantom{-}1 & -1 & -1 & -1 & -1 & \phantom{-}1 & \phantom{-}1 \\
\chi_{(1,(0,0))} &1 &-1 & \phantom{-}1 &-1 & \phantom{-}1 &-1 & \phantom{-}1 &-1\\
\chi_{(1,(0,1))} &1 &-1 & \phantom{-}1 &-1 & -1 & \phantom{-}1 &-1 & \phantom{-}1 \\
\chi_{(1,(1,0))} &1 &-1 & -1 & \phantom{-}1 & \phantom{-}1 & -1 & -1 & \phantom{-}1 \\
\chi_{(1,(1,1))} &1 &-1 & -1 & \phantom{-}1 &-1 & \phantom{-}1 & \phantom{-}1 & -1\\
\end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```

Edit:

This is a similar table that fits perfectly with the default margins which is what I want with my table:

```
\begin{align*}
\setlength\arraycolsep{3pt} % default:5pt
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.2}
\begin{array}{@{} c | *{8}{c} @{}}
  +  & $(0,0,0)$ & $(0,0,1)$ & $(0,1,0)$ & $(0,1,1)$ & $(1,0,0)$ & $(1,0,1)$ & $(1,1,0)$ & $(1,1,1)$\\
    \cline{1-9}
   $(0,0,0)$ & $(0,0,0)$ & $(0,0,1)$ & $(0,1,0)$ & $(0,1,1)$ & $(1,0,0)$ & $(1,0,1)$ & $(1,1,0)$ & $(1,1,1)$\\
    $(0,0,1)$ & $(0,0,1)$ & $(0,0,0)$ & $(0,1,1)$ & $(0,1,0)$ & $(1,0,1)$ & $(1,0,0)$ & $(1,1,1)$ & $(1,1,0)$\\
    $(0,1,0)$ & $(0,1,0)$ & $(0,1,1)$ & $(0,0,0)$ & $(0,0,1)$ & $(1,1,0)$ & $(1,1,1)$ & $(1,0,0)$ & $(1,0,1)$\\
    $(0,1,1)$ & $(0,1,1)$ & $(0,1,0)$ & $(0,0,1)$ & $(0,0,0)$ & $(1,1,1)$ & $(1,1,0)$ & $(1,0,1)$ & $(1,0,0)$\\
    $(1,0,0)$ & $(1,0,0)$ & $(1,0,1)$ & $(1,1,0)$ & $(1,1,1)$ & $(0,0,0)$ & $(0,0,1)$ & $(0,1,0)$ & $(0,1,1)$\\
    $(1,0,1)$ & $(1,0,1)$ & $(1,0,0)$ & $(1,1,1)$ & $(1,1,0)$ & $(0,0,1)$ & $(0,0,0)$ & $(0,1,1)$ & $(0,1,0)$\\
    $(1,1,0)$ & $(1,1,0)$ & $(1,1,1)$ & $(1,0,0)$ & $(1,0,1)$ & $(0,1,0)$ & $(0,1,1)$ & $(0,0,0)$ & $(0,0,1)$\\
    $(1,1,1)$ & $(1,1,1)$ & $(1,1,0)$ & $(1,0,1)$ & $(1,0,0)$ & $(0,1,1)$ & $(0,1,0)$ & $(0,0,1)$ & $(0,0,0)$\\
\end{array}
\end{align*}

The character table:

\[ 
\setlength\arraycolsep{3pt} % default:5pt
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.2}
\begin{array}{@{} c | *{8}{c} @{}}
  +  & (0,0,0) & (0,0,1) & (0,1,0) & (0,1,1) & (1,0,0) & (1,0,1) & (1,1,0) & (1,1,1)\\
\hline
\chi_{(0,0,0)} &1 & \phantom{-}1 & \phantom{-}1 & \phantom{-}1 & \phantom{-}1 & \phantom{-}1 & \phantom{-}1 & \phantom{-}1 \\
\chi_{(0,0,1)} &1 & \phantom{-}1 & \phantom{-}1 & \phantom{-}1 & -1 & -1 & -1 & -1\\
\chi_{(0,1,0)} &1 & \phantom{-}1 & -1 & -1 & \phantom{-}1 & \phantom{-}1 & -1 & -1\\
\chi_{(0,1,1)} &1 & \phantom{-}1 & -1 & -1 & -1 & -1 & \phantom{-}1 & \phantom{-}1 \\
\chi_{(1,0,0)} &1 &-1 & \phantom{-}1 &-1 & \phantom{-}1 &-1 & \phantom{-}1 &-1\\
\chi_{(1,0,1)} &1 &-1 & \phantom{-}1 &-1 & -1 & \phantom{-}1 &-1 & \phantom{-}1 \\
\chi_{(1,1,0)} &1 &-1 & -1 & \phantom{-}1 & \phantom{-}1 & -1 & -1 & \phantom{-}1 \\
\chi_{(1,1,1)} &1 &-1 & -1 & \phantom{-}1 &-1 & \phantom{-}1 & \phantom{-}1 & -1\\
\end{array}
\]
```

Comment: Please, make your MWE really minimal. Remove all what is not relevant to your table and definition of the page layout.

Comment: I need it as its part of a much bigger document which could hinder other things. well I don't know what is necessary and what isn't as im new to latex. this was a template given to me

Comment: Remove all your definition which are not used in table, also all package which are not used in it. And please test reduced table. We need to know only a MWE (Minimal Working Example) which show/demonstrate your problem.

Comment: Is that okay now?

Comment: Much better :-)

Comment: How wide are your document's margins?

Comment: They are the default margins. if you look at the pre-edited question, you shall notice, I didn't set any margins :)

Comment: You could reduce the font size.

Comment: @leandriis the required font it 12pt unfortunately but surely there is a way to fit it nicely?

Comment: @john: Are you allowed to locally change the font size (just for the contents of the table?)

Comment: I believe so however cant we compress the table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I delayed my answer due to lunch :-)

I would try the following:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{amssymb, amsthm,
            mathtools,
            nccmath}
\usepackage{siunitx}

%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
    \footnotesize%\small
    \setlength\tabcolsep{0pt} % default:5pt
    \renewcommand\arraystretch{1.2}
\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}
                             >{$}l<{$} @{\;} | *{8}{c} @{}}
        & (0,(0,0)) & (0,(0,1)) & (0,(1,0)) & (0,(1,1))
        & (1,(0,0)) & (1,(0,1)) & (1,(1,0)) & (1,(1,1)) \\
 \hline
 (0,(0,0)) & (0,(0,0)) & (0,(0,1)) & (0,(1,0)) & (0,(1,1)) & (1,(0,0)) & (1,(0,1)) & (1,(1,0)) & (1,(1,1))\\
 (0,(0,1)) & (0,(0,1)) & (0,(0,0)) & (0,(1,1)) & (0,(1,0)) & (1,(0,1)) & (1,(0,0)) & (1,(1,1)) & (1,(1,0))\\
 (0,(1,0)) & (0,(1,0)) & (0,(1,1)) & (0,(0,0)) & (0,(0,1)) & (1,(1,0)) & (1,(1,1)) & (1,(0,0)) & (1,(0,1))\\
 (0,(1,1)) & (0,(1,1)) & (0,(1,0)) & (0,(0,1)) & (0,(0,0)) & (1,(1,1)) & (1,(1,0)) & (1,(0,1)) & (1,(0,0))\\
 (1,(0,0)) & (1,(0,0)) & (1,(1,0)) & (1,(0,1)) & (1,(1,1)) & (0,(0,0)) & (0,(1,0)) & (0,(0,1)) & (0,(1,1))\\
 (1,(0,1)) & (1,(0,1)) & (1,(1,1)) & (1,(0,0)) & (1,(1,0)) & (0,(0,1)) & (0,(1,1)) & (0,(0,0)) & (0,(1,0))\\
 (1,(1,0)) & (1,(1,0)) & (1,(0,0)) & (1,(1,1)) & (1,(0,1)) & (0,(1,0)) & (0,(0,0)) & (0,(1,1)) & (0,(0,1))\\
 (1,(1,1)) & (1,(1,1)) & (1,(0,1)) & (1,(1,0)) & (1,(0,0)) & (0,(1,1)) & (0,(0,1)) & (0,(1,0)) & (0,(0,0))\\
\end{tabular*}
\end{center}

\begin{center}
    \footnotesize%\small
    \setlength\tabcolsep{0pt} % default:5pt
    \renewcommand\arraystretch{1.2}
\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} 
                             >{$}l<{$} @{\;}| *{8}{S[table-format=-1.0]}}
        & {(0,(0,0))} & {(0,(0,1))} & {(0,(1,0))} & {(0,(1,1))}
        & {(1,(0,0))} & {(1,(0,1))} & {(1,(1,0))} & {(1,(1,1))} \\
\hline
\chi_{(0,(0,0))}    & 1 &  1 &  1 &  1 &  1 &  1 &  1 &  1  \\
\chi_{(0,(0,1))}    & 1 &  1 &  1 &  1 & -1 & -1 & -1 & -1  \\
\chi_{(0,(1,0))}    & 1 &  1 & -1 & -1 &  1 &  1 & -1 & -1  \\
\chi_{(0,(1,1))}    & 1 &  1 & -1 & -1 & -1 & -1 &  1 &  1  \\
\chi_{(1,(0,0))}    & 1 & -1 &  1 & -1 &  1 & -1 &  1 & -1  \\
\chi_{(1,(0,1))}    & 1 & -1 &  1 & -1 & -1 &  1 & -1 &  1  \\
\chi_{(1,(1,0))}    & 1 & -1 & -1 &  1 &  1 & -1 & -1 &  1  \\
\chi_{(1,(1,1))}    & 1 & -1 & -1 &  1 & -1 &  1 &  1 & -1  \\
\end{tabular*}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

it also work if you use `\small` font size.

Comment: Perfecto! I appreciate it greatly :)

Comment: You must have a pretty long lunch hour. :-)

Comment: @Mico, well my wife is very strict about lunch, specially with my help at dish washing after then :-)

Answer (score 1):

With `footnotesize` and a bit less space between the columns the table fits inside the margins:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{nccmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts, graphicx, verbatim, mathtools,amssymb, amsthm, mathrsfs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{floatrow}

\begin{document}

{
\footnotesize
\[
\setlength\arraycolsep{2pt} % default:5pt
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.2}
\begin{array}{@{} c | *{8}{c} @{}}
        & (0,(0,0)) & (0,(0,1)) & (0,(1,0)) & (0,(1,1)) & (1,(0,0)) & (1,(0,1)) & (1,(1,0)) & (1,(1,1))\\
 \hline
 (0,(0,0)) & (0,(0,0)) & (0,(0,1)) & (0,(1,0)) & (0,(1,1)) & (1,(0,0)) & (1,(0,1)) & (1,(1,0)) & (1,(1,1))\\
 (0,(0,1)) & (0,(0,1)) & (0,(0,0)) & (0,(1,1)) & (0,(1,0)) & (1,(0,1)) & (1,(0,0)) & (1,(1,1)) & (1,(1,0))\\
 (0,(1,0)) & (0,(1,0)) & (0,(1,1)) & (0,(0,0)) & (0,(0,1)) & (1,(1,0)) & (1,(1,1)) & (1,(0,0)) & (1,(0,1))\\
 (0,(1,1)) & (0,(1,1)) & (0,(1,0)) & (0,(0,1)) & (0,(0,0)) & (1,(1,1)) & (1,(1,0)) & (1,(0,1)) & (1,(0,0))\\
 (1,(0,0)) & (1,(0,0)) & (1,(1,0)) & (1,(0,1)) & (1,(1,1)) & (0,(0,0)) & (0,(1,0)) & (0,(0,1)) & (0,(1,1))\\
 (1,(0,1)) & (1,(0,1)) & (1,(1,1)) & (1,(0,0)) & (1,(1,0)) & (0,(0,1)) & (0,(1,1)) & (0,(0,0)) & (0,(1,0))\\
 (1,(1,0)) & (1,(1,0)) & (1,(0,0)) & (1,(1,1)) & (1,(0,1)) & (0,(1,0)) & (0,(0,0)) & (0,(1,1)) & (0,(0,1))\\
 (1,(1,1)) & (1,(1,1)) & (1,(0,1)) & (1,(1,0)) & (1,(0,0)) & (0,(1,1)) & (0,(0,1)) & (0,(1,0)) & (0,(0,0))\\
\end{array}
\]
}

{
\footnotesize
\[ % no need for an 'align*' env.
\setlength\arraycolsep{2pt} % default:5pt
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.2}
\begin{array}{@{} c | *{8}{c} @{}}
    & (0,(0,0)) & (0,(0,1)) & (0,(1,0)) & (0,(1,1)) & (1,(0,0)) & (1,(0,1)) & (1,(1,0)) & (1,(1,1))\\
\hline
\chi_{(0,(0,0))} &1 & \phantom{-}1 & \phantom{-}1 & \phantom{-}1 & \phantom{-}1 & \phantom{-}1 & \phantom{-}1 & \phantom{-}1 \\
\chi_{(0,(0,1))} &1 & \phantom{-}1 & \phantom{-}1 & \phantom{-}1 & -1 & -1 & -1 & -1\\
\chi_{(0,(1,0))} &1 & \phantom{-}1 & -1 & -1 & \phantom{-}1 & \phantom{-}1 & -1 & -1\\
\chi_{(0,(1,1))} &1 & \phantom{-}1 & -1 & -1 & -1 & -1 & \phantom{-}1 & \phantom{-}1 \\
\chi_{(1,(0,0))} &1 &-1 & \phantom{-}1 &-1 & \phantom{-}1 &-1 & \phantom{-}1 &-1\\
\chi_{(1,(0,1))} &1 &-1 & \phantom{-}1 &-1 & -1 & \phantom{-}1 &-1 & \phantom{-}1 \\
\chi_{(1,(1,0))} &1 &-1 & -1 & \phantom{-}1 & \phantom{-}1 & -1 & -1 & \phantom{-}1 \\
\chi_{(1,(1,1))} &1 &-1 & -1 & \phantom{-}1 &-1 & \phantom{-}1 & \phantom{-}1 & -1\\
\end{array}
\]
}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

this link might help you: [How do I properly resize an array?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/320431/how-do-i-properly-resize-an-array)

Also, I tried to follow the link to modify your code and this is what I got:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{report}
\def\A{A}
\def\B{B}
\def\false{\ne}
\def\true{=}
\usepackage{graphicx,amsmath}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{nccmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts, graphicx, verbatim, mathtools,amssymb, amsthm, mathrsfs}
\usepackage{array}
    \usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{floatrow}


\begin{document}


\setlength\arraycolsep{3pt} % default:5pt
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.2}
\begin{itemize}
\item \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{$\displaystyle

\begin{array}{@{} c | *{8}{c} @{}}
        & (0,(0,0)) & (0,(0,1)) & (0,(1,0)) & (0,(1,1)) & (1,(0,0)) & (1,(0,1)) & (1,(1,0)) & (1,(1,1))\\
 \hline
 (0,(0,0)) & (0,(0,0)) & (0,(0,1)) & (0,(1,0)) & (0,(1,1)) & (1,(0,0)) & (1,(0,1)) & (1,(1,0)) & (1,(1,1))\\
 (0,(0,1)) & (0,(0,1)) & (0,(0,0)) & (0,(1,1)) & (0,(1,0)) & (1,(0,1)) & (1,(0,0)) & (1,(1,1)) & (1,(1,0))\\
 (0,(1,0)) & (0,(1,0)) & (0,(1,1)) & (0,(0,0)) & (0,(0,1)) & (1,(1,0)) & (1,(1,1)) & (1,(0,0)) & (1,(0,1))\\
 (0,(1,1)) & (0,(1,1)) & (0,(1,0)) & (0,(0,1)) & (0,(0,0)) & (1,(1,1)) & (1,(1,0)) & (1,(0,1)) & (1,(0,0))\\
 (1,(0,0)) & (1,(0,0)) & (1,(1,0)) & (1,(0,1)) & (1,(1,1)) & (0,(0,0)) & (0,(1,0)) & (0,(0,1)) & (0,(1,1))\\
 (1,(0,1)) & (1,(0,1)) & (1,(1,1)) & (1,(0,0)) & (1,(1,0)) & (0,(0,1)) & (0,(1,1)) & (0,(0,0)) & (0,(1,0))\\
 (1,(1,0)) & (1,(1,0)) & (1,(0,0)) & (1,(1,1)) & (1,(0,1)) & (0,(1,0)) & (0,(0,0)) & (0,(1,1)) & (0,(0,1))\\
 (1,(1,1)) & (1,(1,1)) & (1,(0,1)) & (1,(1,0)) & (1,(0,0)) & (0,(1,1)) & (0,(0,1)) & (0,(1,0)) & (0,(0,0))\\
\end{array}$

 }
    \end{itemize}




\setlength\arraycolsep{3pt} % default:5pt
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.2}
\begin{itemize}
\item \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{$\displaystyle
\begin{array}{@{} c | *{8}{c} @{}}
    & (0,(0,0)) & (0,(0,1)) & (0,(1,0)) & (0,(1,1)) & (1,(0,0)) & (1,(0,1)) & (1,(1,0)) & (1,(1,1))\\
\hline
\chi_{(0,(0,0))} &1 & \phantom{-}1 & \phantom{-}1 & \phantom{-}1 & \phantom{-}1 & \phantom{-}1 & \phantom{-}1 & \phantom{-}1 \\
\chi_{(0,(0,1))} &1 & \phantom{-}1 & \phantom{-}1 & \phantom{-}1 & -1 & -1 & -1 & -1\\
\chi_{(0,(1,0))} &1 & \phantom{-}1 & -1 & -1 & \phantom{-}1 & \phantom{-}1 & -1 & -1\\
\chi_{(0,(1,1))} &1 & \phantom{-}1 & -1 & -1 & -1 & -1 & \phantom{-}1 & \phantom{-}1 \\
\chi_{(1,(0,0))} &1 &-1 & \phantom{-}1 &-1 & \phantom{-}1 &-1 & \phantom{-}1 &-1\\
\chi_{(1,(0,1))} &1 &-1 & \phantom{-}1 &-1 & -1 & \phantom{-}1 &-1 & \phantom{-}1 \\
\chi_{(1,(1,0))} &1 &-1 & -1 & \phantom{-}1 & \phantom{-}1 & -1 & -1 & \phantom{-}1 \\
\chi_{(1,(1,1))} &1 &-1 & -1 & \phantom{-}1 &-1 & \phantom{-}1 & \phantom{-}1 & -1\\
\end{array}$
 }
    \end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Try it! and I'm not sure if this will satisfy you or not.

Regards,

Comment: I am getting errors as I defined A as something else and also getting errors before the first 'end{itemize}'

Comment: I don't have any errors! did you copy and paste my code as it is? I removed from your code "\[" and "\]".

Comment: I opened a new document, copied your code and still got errors! no worries though.